# How to get response body of a post request without escape sequences in Java?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to convert the HttpResponse's response body to a String using the following piece of code:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
response = client.execute(request);
EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), standardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
```

The expected response after converting it to a String is as follows:

```
{"errors": ["permission denied"]}
```

This code was working fine until recently. But now the response body is somehow being modified to this:

```
{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
```

I do not understand how the "1 error occurred" message is being inserted into the response body as the response from the same call in Postman gives me the appropriate response i.e.:

`{"errors": ["permission denied"]}`

And I've checked the code thoroughly and am certain that the "1 error occurred" message is not being inserted manually.

#### EDIT:

These were the response headers from Postman:

```
cache-control →no-store
content-length →33
content-type →application/json
date →Thu, 30 May 2019 06:52:33 GMT
status →403
```

And these were the response headers from the HttpClient call:

```
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 30 May 2019 09:06:21 GMT
Content-Length: 60
```

The only difference is that the status code isn't being printed. But checking the status code through the `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` yields 403 as well.

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with the HTTP client you are using. You should at least specify which client you are using. My guess is that the server replies in a different way to postman and your java request, possibly because of headers or the protocol used...

Comment: I am using Apache httpclient v4.1

Comment: I'm quite sure httpclient is not rewriting the response body.

Comment: did you update the httpClient jar? check if the entityUtils or the to String method is updated to return different values

Comment: "permission denied" is some object in server.. it looks like the toString was updated to check number of errors and print them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Apache HttpClient, which does not modify responses this way. It's definitely the response generated by server. Check your configuration of request in Postman to see if there are any additional headers, that may alter server behavior.